# How do I test futures in clojure?

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, midje

I'm trying to use midje to test a future, but I can't seem to get it to work.

The code looks like

```
(defn foo []
  (let [f (future (bar))]
    (baz @f))
```

With a test like

```
(fact 
  (foo) => ..a..
  (provided
    (bar) => ..b..
    (baz ..b..) => ..a..))
```

This fails, saying that bar never gets called. Any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code shows that midje test wait until the dereferencing future var, so i think midje with futures is not your problem but other in the sequence functions you have

```
(defn foo []
  (let [state (future (Thread/sleep 1000) (println "done") "done")]
      @state
    )

  )
(fact "description of the fact"
      "done" => (foo))
==>true
```

Good luck!